# Installation error in Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, rufus

I have an AMD A10 with 4GB RAM.

This error keeps on occurring whenever I boot into any version of Ubuntu installation through USB. The error keeps on occurring. I have the same problem with every Linux distro including 64-bit Ubuntu. Ubuntu 32-bit was fine, but Ubuntu 64-bit shows the problem in the below image when I boot into my bootable USB.

[image]

I used Rufus for creating a bootable USB. My laptop is only 3 months old. I also tried on the second day after buying my laptop, but this problem occurred at that time too. 
There is no hardware issue, and the bootable Ubuntu USB works in another laptop too, but in mine this error occurs.

Comment: From what device are you trying to install these Ubuntu's?

Comment: I/O error has to do with a problem reading the installation/live media. Either the ISO is corrupt, the tool used to make the USB created the issue, the USB drive is faulty, some hardware problem preventing it from reading, etc. Please [edit] and describe how did you make the USB. Also, for AMD A10 APUs use 64-bit only.

Comment: With Rufus you have to explicitly select MBR or GPT. You need GPT for UEFI. That's why it works on your older, BIOS based, computer.

Comment: I have tried evry possible thing.. i tried with gpt for uefi.. and i also tried for mbr.. but problem still occurs..

Comment: Are there any other USB ports on the laptop you could try? Sometimes just using a different port works.

Comment: Ya i tried.. but didn't work